# Use CSS to keep top level navigation hover effect on when mouse is over submenu

Tags: css, navigation, nav

I want to make my top level navigation stay on the hover state while I'm hovering on the submenu items. I read that I should apply the hover effect to the li, but there are some transitions that are confusing the situation for me. I can't figure it out. Can someone tell me where I need to adjust this?

[my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imakeitpretty/zwVwh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to apply the `:hover` effect to the li and apply the CSS to the direct `a` child. Applying the hover to the `a` won't work because the submenus of the top-level links aren't in the `a` element.

```
ul#navigation .topNav:hover > a {
    color:#acb453;
    padding-top:0;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #4dbaf2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zwVwh/12/